# VIm function that runs file through shfmt

Tags: formatting, child-process, vimscript

I've written a Vim function that formats the file using shfmt. I'd like to know if there is a way I can improve this script.

I am bothered by the fact that I can't think of a way to do this without editing the file in the subprocess and reloading the file. Is there a way to do the equivalent of `%!shfmt -options`?

```
if exists("g:loaded_shfmt") || &compatible || ! executable('shfmt')
  finish
endif

let s:save_cpoptions = &cpoptions
set cpoptions&vim

let s:switches = join(['-w', '-s', '-i', '2', '-bn', '-ci', '-sr'])

function! s:shFormat()
  let l:filename = @%
  let l:out = system('shfmt ' . s:switches . ' ' . l:filename)
  edit!
endfunction

nnoremap <silent> <Leader>fb :call <SID>shFormat()<CR>

let &cpoptions = s:save_cpoptions

let g:loaded_shfmt = 1
```